# Где нужно применение ООП, а где нет

Tags: ооп, php

Приветствую всех вошедших

```
//самый обычный PHP код
$a=5;

//самый обычный PHP код, с комментарием
$a=5;//Это переменная $a, мы присваиваем ей значение 5 (с) Всегда ваш кэп
```

Разница в комментарии. Я их люблю, много, и с примерами, но простейшие вещи пояснять все же не надо. Вот учу ООП, по ссылкам и видео урокам по совету от сюда, дело идет, и все не так страшно, как думал, но не понимаю в каких конкретных случаях нужно использовать код с ООП, а где без.

```
//Например:
//1. делаем запрос к бд -> в цикле выводим статьи
//2. делаем запрос к бд -> выводим товар, со всеми его свойствами
//Тут ооп нужен? может кто то еще, что то добавить?
```

Comment: А где, прости, в примерах хоть раз упоминание про ООП?

>но не понимаю в каких конкретных случаях нужно использовать код с ООП, а где без.

Зачем было задавать вопрос, если ты не знаешь для чего применять ООП?!

Comment: @Shrek, я просто вижу такой алгоритм, что: 1. сначала идет запрос к БД, 2. потом вывод информации, 3. Profit. Что собственно и описал. А вот как использовать ООП в этой конструкции не понимаю. Можете объяснить? Или это нужно как то по другому использовать?

Comment: @frank а вам прямо кровь из носу нужно запихнуть сюда ООП? Зачем оно вам так понадобилось, если вы даже не понимаете, для чего оно нужно?

Comment: Советую почитать  еще и про MVC чтобы отбросить вопросы про то как использовать ООП

Comment: ну кто, кто советует вам видеоуроки? это маразм учить языки программирования по видео.

Comment: @Shrek, хорошо, уже есть куда копать

Comment: >это маразм учить языки программирования по виде

небось еще по Попову какому-нибудь, прости Господи

Comment: По видео, как раз у меня пошло лучше, чем по книге. А учил по ссылке в одной из прошлых тем (Пользователь: @Сержо; Ссылка: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6xWUUv93Vk). За неимением ничего лучше, и это сгодиться!

Comment: >По видео, как раз у меня пошло лучше, чем по книге

остается только посочувствовать

Comment: @frank, откуда вы знаете, что сгодится? Судя по вопросу, не очень-то и сгодилось. А ведь гугл на этот затертый вопрос даст тысячи ответов. Неумение искать информацию самому - конец карьеры.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.php

Comment: Не трогайте Поповых - это девичья фамилия моей матери)

@frank, здесь уже спрашивали несколько раз про это. Вы читали ответы на те вопросы?

ООП - это инструмент. Применяете его тогда, когда он вам нужен. Если не нужен - не применяете.

Гвозди тоже можно кувалдой забивать, но стоит ли? С одной стороны, здесь "кувалда" - ООП, когда речь идет именно о "гвоздях". С другой стороны - "кувалда" - это функции, которые могут выполнить поставленную задачу, но с использованием ООП она решится куда элегантнее.

Comment: >Не трогайте Поповых - это девичья фамилия моей матери)

боюсь, из-за этого замечательного обстоятельства видеоуроки от г-на Е.Попова лучше не станут. Впрочем, эту же прекрасную фамилию носил куда более достойный человек - изобретатель радио Александр Попов

Comment: @frank а вас не насторожило [вот в этом ответе](http://hashcode.ru/questions/222286#222394) на дубликат этого-же вопроса что Серж занимается этим всего 3 недели (внутреннее понимание конечно может при этом появится, но тренерский навык вряд-ли)

Comment: @DreamChild Попов тут наверное непричём, видеоуроки по программированию, это всё равно что учиться ушу по радио.

Comment: @xEdelweis - сгодиться. Просто когда пойму ГДЕ этот ооп нужен, применю, просто копаю не в том направлении. @eicto - с этого я и начал. @BOPOH - Аа! В принципе да, более накручено чем обычная функция, это уже похоже на правду.

Не знаю кто, и чем занимается 3 недели, у меня пока 1 неделя неразберихи с ооп. Сейчас пойду читать про MVC, и буду смотреть на ООП как на функции, или как на способ обработки данных перед выводом.

Даже акцепт влепить некому 8-/

Comment: Эхъ... не так меня поняли... Может быть для этого время надо? Глядишь - потом само как-то придет...

Смотреть на ООП как на функцию - все равно, что смотреть на девушку как на "предмет согревающий кровать".

Не надо думать - беру левую ногу, переставляю ее вперед, затем беру правую - так же вперед. А потом оказывается, что про корпус-то забыли. И попой на асфальте оказались.

ООП - это "иду в магазин и беру пиво". Все. А вот как именно иду в магазин и как именно покупаю пиво - это уже реализация.

Только не надо думать, что ООП - это про пиво))

Comment: Почитайте [вот эти ответы](/questions/170336/).

Comment: @VladD а как Вы считаете, коррелирует ли распространение ООП с тем фактом, что последние десятилетия отрасль деньгами явно перекормлена? (т.е. что помогает решать ООП -- конкретную техническую проблему или освоение средств на решение этой проблемы)

Comment: @alexlz: это взаимосвязано. Если раньше писались тулзы командной строки без сложного поведения, их мог разрабатывать один человек, сложной внутренней логики не было, и можно было обходиться и без классов. Когда денег в отрасли много, хочется потратить их и получить сложное поведение, а значит, сложность логики возрастает, превышая способности одного программиста, значит, нужно деление на независимые подзадачи и инкапсуляция внутренней логики и данных, автоматически ООП становится желанным, а часто и необходимым, как простейший путь абстракции.

Comment: Кто-то не может изучать основы без преподавателя. Некоторым гораздо проще учить по видео\скринкастам. А кому-то не подходит ни то, ни другое, и только книги да маны способны пролить свет. Причем некоторым подходят только бумажные книги...

Всё это субъективно и не повод для высокомерного сочувствия.

Comment: @VladD Всяко бывает

       Unfortunately, programmers coming in from other languages
where objects are the norm tend to use OCaml’s objects as a matter of course, to their detriment. In the hundreds of thousands of lines of OCaml at Jane Street, there are only a handful of uses of objects, and most of those could be eliminated without much pain.
       Caml Trading: Experiences in Functional Programming on Wall
Street by Yaron Minsky

А насчёт абстракций и ООП -- это к редактору OOPSLA (ежели не перепутал) R.Gabriel'ю

Comment: @alexlz: А вы видели проект на 1М строк на OCaml'е? Я к тому, что в OCaml'овских проектах обычно не приходится описывается сложное поведение, не приходится работать с гетерогенными библиотеками и скрывать особенности чужого кода, не нужен такой вид абстракции.

Насчёт P. Gabriel — может, процитируете или подкинете ссылку?

Comment: @VladD
      
      А вы видели проект на 1М строк на OCaml'е?

Бог миловал. Насчёт сложного поведения -- бездоказательно, скорее наоборот, алгебраические типы данных способствуют. По выразительности и кратости OCaml вроде получше perl'а... Насчёт Gabriel'я -- http://www.dreamsongs.com/Files/PatternsOfSoftware.pdf (правда это прошлое тысячелетие)

Comment: @DreamChild, ох смотрю Попов вас прямо таки в попу ужалил. Ох и досадил он Вам я смотрю... Везде его упоминаете.. Прямо-таки личная неприязнь!

Comment: @alexlz: Почитал эссе, и не согласился. Претензии автора сводятся к тому, что плохая абстракция оставляет программиста в таком же состоянии, как и без абстракции. И что абстракция внезапно не решает всех проблем в программировании. Ну так второе самоочевидно, а первое говорит о том, что абстракция как минимум не хуже чем её отсутствие.

Мой тезис таков: большие проекты на языках, не позволяющих эффективную абстракцию, невозможны, так как превышают способности человека держать в уме детали. А маленькие проекты можно писать хоть на ассемблере. Если на OCaml'е нет больших проектов, это звоночек.

Comment: >По видео, как раз у меня пошло лучше, чем по книге

И в чем проблема? Конечно полностью учится программированию по видео это маразм, но я не вижу проблемы в том, что человек быстрее понимает что к чему посмотрев то, как это делают другие в режиме "реального времени", другое дело - надо понимать что далеко не факт, что все что вы увидели правильно и т.д., но на мой взляд это куда продуктивнее чем курить 100500 строчные маны, не?

Кстати на вопрос ТСа книги не отвечают, да и вообще на этот вопрос ответа нет и вообще он долэен был быть уже давным давно закрытым

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ООП имеет смысл использовать, когда нужно работать с какой-то сложной единицей информации.
ООП существует для удобства организации данных.

Например, вполне можно сделать класс для соединения с базой данных и выполнения к ней разных запросов. Чтобы у класса было поле с идентификатором соединения, например, дабы не плодить лишние переменные. А можно организовать классы для статей и для товаров. Или класс для каталога товаров и статей. Или классы для всего вышеперечисленного.

ООП применять вовсе не обязательно. Мой дядя как-то сказал мне "ООП существует только в ваших головах". Другое дело, что ООП это очень удобно. Удобно хранить данные, организовывать методы доступа к этим данным и создавать инструменты на будущее.

Класс баз данных, который я написал пару лет назад, я использую до сих пор в каждом своём проекте. За пару лет своего развития он стал для меня практически совершенством.

Мой совет: попробуй применять классы для всего и везде, где можешь. Со временем понимание мест, где можно было бы обойтись без этого, придёт само.

Comment: ООП -- это тема для холивара. Хорошая тема для хорошего холивара.

Comment: @alexlz: хорошо, тогда начинаем?

Comment: @alexlz: хорошая тема для хорошего холивара на уроке информатики в старших классах школы, да xD

Answer (score 2):

Еще раз вставлю свои 5 копеек.
Уже прошло чуть больше месяца после того как я начал изучать ООП.

Когда я начал писать на ООП, мне не понятно было зачем писать именно так. Но со временем прощупал возможности, и приходили мысли "так я же могу теперь создать такую конструкцию".

**Практика и еще раз практика!**

Видео курсы помогли мне войти в курс дела. После чего я начал практиковаться, переводить все свои функции для работы с бд в классы (ради получения опыта). После некоторого времени практики, я стал читать книгу по ООП, где примеры из книги расширили мои знания.
Сейчас: я читаю книгу по ООП/ изучаю фреймверк Yii/ читаю книгу по Yii / и конечно же практикую.

Ради получения опыта перевожу один простенький сайт из процедурок на ооп фреймверк Yii.

*(кто то, там сочувствует по поводу обучения через видео? Видео-уроки это школа - только без интерактива)*

Comment: @Сержо, привет 8-) Мы как раз тебя ждем. Почту на ютубе проверь

Comment: Пусто. да и я не давал свой акк на ютьюбе вроде

Comment: Есть одна книга для Perl, в которой ООП не затрагивается. Так вот к ней идет примечание, что книга для приложений до 100 строк кода. Думаю это наверное и есть ответ на твой вопрос.

Comment: Отправил тому, кто создал видео. Можно было и подписаться!

Comment: @Сержо, а просто структурному программированию (оно же процедурное) с модульным проектированием сверху вниз (старый, традиционный подход) Вы сколько времени уделили?

Comment: @avp: Я бы не называл этот подход «старым», потому что «старый» неявно подразумевает «устаревший». А структурное программирование никак не устарело.